# Shifting a value and creating a new index using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`

```
            2019            2020            2021            2022

A           10              20              30              40
```

I am trying to create 2 new indexes `A-1` and `A-2` so that the output would look like this:

```
            2019            2020            2021            2022

A           10              20              30              40
A-1         nan             10              20              40
A-2         nan             nan             10              20
```

I tried:

```
s = df.loc['A',:].shift(1, axis=0)
s = s.rename({'A': 'A-1'}, axis = 0)
df = df.combine_first(s)
```

But I get an error at
`----> 3 df= df.combine_first(s)`

> ValueError: Must specify axis=0 or 1

When I add `axis = 0` I get:

> TypeError: combine_first() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

So I am not sure where is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a bit your strategy. `combine_first` is not appropriate here.

Rather use `concat`, and keep the data as DataFrame:

```
pd.concat([df, df.loc[['A']].shift(1, axis=1).rename(index={'A': 'A-1'})])
```

output:

```
     2019  2020  2021  2022
A    10.0    20    30    40
A-1   NaN    10    20    30
```

##### shift programmatically

If you need to have many shifts, do it programmatically:

```
n = 3
df2 = pd.concat([df]+[(df.loc[['A']].shift(i+1, axis=1)
                         .rename(index={'A': f'A-{i+1}'})
                      ) for i in range(n)])
```

output:

```
     2019  2020  2021  2022
A    10.0  20.0  30.0    40
A-1   NaN  10.0  20.0    30
A-2   NaN   NaN  10.0    20
A-3   NaN   NaN   NaN    10
```

###### using Series

If really you only need to shift a single row, it is easier to work with Series:

```
n = 3
row = 'A'
s = df.loc[row]
df2 = pd.concat([s]+[s.shift(i+1).rename(f'{row}-{i+1}') for i in range(n)],
                axis=1).T
```

output:

```
     2019  2020  2021  2022
A    10.0  20.0  30.0    40
A-1   NaN  10.0  20.0    30
A-2   NaN   NaN  10.0    20
A-3   NaN   NaN   NaN    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Juste use `loc` to create your new indexes

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({2019:[10], 2020:[20], 2021:[30], 2022:[40]}, index=["A"])
>>> df.loc["A-1"] = df.loc["A"].shift()
>>> df.loc["A-2"] = df.loc["A-1"].shift()
>>> df
     2019  2020  2021  2022
A    10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0
A-1   NaN  10.0  20.0  30.0
A-2   NaN   NaN  10.0  20.0
```